# Error en los modulos al configurar un webpack con ReactJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, webpack

Tengo un error a la hora de configurar un webpack con Reactjs. Me sale este error que esta a continuación y desearía una explicación.

El error que me sale en la terminal es el siguiente:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\react\index.js' 
in 'C:\react' npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! 
platzivideo@1.0.0 build:prod: webpack -p --env.NODE_ENV=production npm 
ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the platzivideo@1.0.0 
build:prod script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. 
There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! 
C:\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-22T21_33_42_548Z-debug.log
```

---

Aquí dejo como es mi webpack.config

```js
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = (env) => {
  const plugins = [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name].[hash].css")
  ]

  if (env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    plugins.push(
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {root: __dirname})
    )
  }

  return {

    entry: {
      "plaztivideo": path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.js'),
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'js/[name].[hash].js',
      publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')+"/",
      chunkFilename: 'js/[id].[chunkhash].js',
    },
    devServer: {
      port: 9000,
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2'],
            }
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  minimize: true,
                }
              }
            ]
          })
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              fallback: 'file-loader',
              name: 'images/[name].[hash].[ext]',
            }
          }
        },
      ]
    },
    plugins
  }
}
```

Comment: cual es el contenido del log? `C:\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-22T21_33_42_548Z-debug.log
`

Comment: He dejado como fue que hice el webpack

Comment: dale click a [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/198596/edit) y agrega la info a la pregunta. el log sería interesante de ver.

Comment: ahh vale, gracias no sabia esa parte.
Estoy buscando el log. Es que este proyecto lo tengo de hace tiempo y lo avía dejado a un lado. ahora volví a tomarlo para terminal el proyecto.